# LPBoost in Matlab2013b

Tags: matlab

Can someone explain the decision tree modeling in Matlab? I saw the help in Matlab, but they have provided an example without explaining how to use the parameters in the `classficationtree.template` function. I have started my research which involves decision tree implementation. Any help to explain the use of `classficationtree.template` with its parameters will be appreciated.

Comment: On each MATLAB help page, usually on the bottom right corner you can provide feedback, as well as require an enhancement to the docs. They usually get back in a couple of days, which would be more effective than asking here, imo.

Comment: hi,i wonder in regresion.tree how can i find out cutpoint how work and how i can claculate c = cuttype(t) returns an n-element
cell array c indicating the type of cut at each
node in the tree t, where n is
the number of nodes. For each node i, c{i} is: